# Enterprise Architect Reverse Engineering - Associations

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have imported Sources in the Enterprise Architect and want to draw both class and sequence diagrams.

### Class diagram

The issue here is, if I pull a class from the project browser to the "drawing stage", the members of this class are displayed within the class. How can I get the associations instead of (or in addition to) the members? So if I have a class Builder with a member Room. I want to have both classes and a association between these two. Do I have to pull all the members manually on the "drawing stage" or is there some automatic processing?

### Sequence diagram

Can I let the EA draw a sequence diagram for me with just a "starting method" as input?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the sequence diagram question. Could you clarify please? What would you like EA to do besides create the diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Class diagram**

Yes, you can add associated classes. Drop the class onto the diagram, then right-click it and select Add - Related Elements. This causes EA to add to the diagram other elements which have a connector to or from the element you right-clicked.

In the dialog EA opens you can specify a single element type (class, component, etc) to be added and/or a single connector type ("link" in this dialog), eg association, to be followed. Leaving either blank will result in EA adding all element types and/or following all connectors.

You can also specify the connector direction (if for instance you want to add only those directed associations going *from* the first class, not the ones going *to* it), as well as the number of links to follow in a chain ("levels").

If you want to hide the members for a specific class, you can right-click the class and select Set Feature Visibility, which brings up a dialog where you can switch the various compartments on or off for that class.

If instead you want to change the presentation of all classes in the diagram you can double-click an empty area of the diagram (or right-click and select Properties), and set presentation of the various compartments in the Elements tab.